# How to solve kotlin cacheconfig error

Tags: android, kotlin

I use CacheConfig in Kotlin 1.2
so, I faced "unresolved reference: CacheConfig" Error

Code

```
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = ["books", "default"])
public class BookRepositoryImpl {
    // ...
}
```

Log

hi.kt:1:2: error: unresolved reference: CacheConfig
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = ["books", "default"])

Comment: Where is your code? Where is your log? Consider editing your question.

Comment: Im sorry for miss that. I put code & log!

Comment: That piece of code is from the “What’s new in Kotlin 1.2” article. Are you just pasting code from it to play around with it or you’re trying to build a spring app? Because it’s a Spring annotation.

Comment: @Strelok ah? these code are spring code?
I try to use cacheconfig in androidstudio!